# Video Live Embed from external websites

Tags: video, live, broadcasting

I want to make a website where visitors can view webcams from the world. I want to make categories per countries, a map etc. The problem is that 90% of webcams i find on internet are .mjpg or .cgi. So, i've made a code that make this mjpg working in IE 8,9 etc. I can't put links to these websites that contains these webcams because on their sites, these streams doesn't work in IE. So I need to load the image in HTML:  from their website.

Is legally to load the stream form these external sites? Must I put a link above the picture to their website? What can I do to be legally? I want to make this site without external links for viewing of the stream.

If this question is not appropriate for asking here, please leave a comment, and I will delete it (please tell me where can I ask this question).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This questions appears to be more about web development and etiquette than audio/video production as you are simply reusing an existing stream rather than making your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is called hot linking, and while it may or may not technically be a violation of their copyright or terms of use (check their website for details) it is still generally considered a poor practice since you are effectively utilizing their bandwidth without mentioning that it is their bandwidth.

Your best bet is to contact the operators of those cameras and ask them what they think.

Comment: Thank you. I want to use hot linking. May I put in the description: "Source: http....website" ? (to be legal)

Comment: @ITChristian - it depends entirely on the terms of service (if any) on the site in question.  They are making the content publicly available, but if their terms of service say they don't allow direct linking, then you would be doing the digital equivalent of trespassing by using their resources in a way they don't allow.  The best bet is to check with them and let them know what you want to do.